# auto get element id on html

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am developing one account management applications available to users. My current application can log the user account on the website. But I am having a difficult is that each site has a unique id for each of the username / password in html. So no way to automatically retrieve the ids of username / password in the html file. I'm developing my app on android and webview used for web browsing. Thanks for help.

```
final String js = "javascript:function()document.getElementById('username').value='username';})(‌​)";
final String js1 = "javascript:function()document.getElementById('pass').value='pass';})()";     
final String js2 = "javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].click();})()";
```

Comment: above code is working but when i go to another website then username/password id change so my code didn't work

Comment: please edit your question and add the code there. Don't put all your code in the comment.

Comment: Atleast for the password you could try `document.querySelector("input[type=password]")` which should give you the first password input in the document. But it is not 100% reliable.

Comment: thank. your code is working. but i have some problem. i used above code for username field but it is not working because it have many text type in html so do you have any way to get username field in webview ?